# Listing Nested Resources in Filament Admin

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested-sets, laravel-filament, laravel-eloquent-resource

I'm working with Laravel, Filament Admin panel, and staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list.

I'm struggling to bring this nested tree structure into the CategoryResource List table through getEloquentQuery() properly.

I have a resource (Categories) which has a hasMany relationship to itself.
The DB looks like this:
"categories"

- id
- parent_id
- name

I can pass this through to get partially there:

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
     return parent::getEloquentQuery()->tree()->depthFirst();
}
```

This does create a nested set of records that has the child Categories listed directly underneath their parent Category.

However this leads to 2 issues that are not ideal:

- First, when working with other plugins like alperenersoy/filament-export this seems to break functionality. The CTE query passed through getEloquentQuery causes an error when trying to export through the alperenersoy package (reverting to a simple getEloquentQuery has the package working properly).
- Second, ideally these nested records in the CategoryResource List table would be also respect an alphabetical order based on their names at their nested level. For example, if we have a Parent Category named "Blue Plan" with 2 child Categories are named "AAA Plan" and "CCC Plan", I would like the Categories to list like so:
  "Blue Plan"
  "AAA Plan"
  "CCC Plan"

---

I've tried several variations of modifying the resource's getEloquentQuery().
First I attempted to modify the output from the laravel-adjacency-list package:

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    $sql = parent::getEloquentQuery()->getExpressionGrammar()->compileOrderByPath();
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -5);

    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->tree()->orderByRaw($sql . '), name ASC');
}
```

Then I tried some variations on recursive query constraints

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
$tree = Category::withRecursiveQueryConstraint(function (Builder $query) {
   $query->where('categories.name', '=', 'ADVENT');
   $query->orderBy('name');
   }, function () {
        return parent::getEloquentQuery()->tree()->depthFirst();
   });
return $tree;
}
```